# I want to make an appointment system for my website. I am having issues with the structure

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I am building an appointment system for a project. The system is for a repair service. I want the form to be made with the hiding div system, which is basically as soon as the button is clicked a new div is visible and the previous one gets hidden.

I am making this website as a webapp in flask.
I designed the first div to be the buttons which i want to be the first field of the form

```
<div id="step2" class="formStep">
 <h2>Step 2: Select Device Company</h2>
 <div class="buttonGroup">
  <button class="optionButton" data-value="phone">Phone</button>
  <button class="optionButton" data-value="laptop">Laptop</button>
  <button class="optionButton" data-value="tablet">Tablet</button>
  <button class="optionButton" data-value="desktop">Desktop</button>
  <button class="optionButton" data-value="other">Other Repair</button>
 </div>
 <button onclick="prevStep(1)">Back</button>
 <button id="continueButton" onclick="nextStep(3)" disabled>Continue</button>
</div>
```

these are the buttons when we select any button the continue button gets activated using

```
function selectOptionButton(button) {
            const optionButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.optionButton');
            optionButtons.forEach(btn => {
                btn.classList.remove('selected');
            });

            button.classList.add('selected');
            const continueButton = document.getElementById('continueButton');
            continueButton.removeAttribute('disabled'); // Enable the Continue button
            updateDeviceModelOptions();
        }
```

this script and the next div gets activated with this

```
const formSteps = document.querySelectorAll('.formStep');
        let currentStep = 1;

        function nextStep(next) {
            formSteps[currentStep - 1].style.display = 'none';
            formSteps[next - 1].style.display = 'block';
            currentStep = next;
            updateStep(next);
        }

        function prevStep(prev) {
            formSteps[currentStep - 1].style.display = 'none';
            formSteps[prev - 1].style.display = 'block';
            currentStep = prev;
            updateStep(prev);
        }
```

but in the second div if the user select any option i want the options in the second div to be displayed accordingly.

eg: if the user selects phone in the first div it should show him the cellphones we repair like samsung, iphone, moto,etc and as soon as they select the company of the cellphone and as soon as they click continue they see the models of the company we repair like iphone 11, 12, 13

but for each device, each company the visible options should be different. If anyone can help me out with it thanks.

i tried using the js code

```
function updateDeviceCompanyOptions() {
            const deviceType = document.getElementById('deviceType').value;
            const deviceCompany = document.getElementById('deviceCompany');
            deviceCompany.innerHTML = '';

            const companies = {
                phone: ['Samsung', 'Apple', 'LG', 'Motorola', 'Others'],
                laptop: ['Apple', 'Samsung', 'Acer', 'Asus', 'Dell', 'HP', 'Lenovo', 'Others'],
                tablet: ['Apple', 'Samsung'],
                desktop: ['Apple', 'Samsung', 'Acer', 'Asus', 'Dell', 'HP', 'Others'],
                other: []
            };

            companies[deviceType].forEach(company => {
                const option = document.createElement('button');
                option.classList.add('optionButton');
                option.textContent = company;
                option.dataset.value = company;
                option.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    selectOptionButton(option);
                });
                deviceCompany.appendChild(option);
            });
        }
```

but it is not working out as i want cause i want them to be in the button format

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't just say 'it is not working out'. Say exactly what is happening
2. Separate from the question you asked, I'm going to suggest the following changes to improve your design

   a. For 'select device', since a user can only select one type of device, use [input type="radio"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio). Using radio buttons means you can drop the code where you cycle through all of the buttons and remove the selected class and then add the selected class to the button the user chose.

   b. With radio buttons, you can set a default value and the next Div will show the corresponding values for the selected option. Then each time user changes the selection in the first div (selects a new radio button), the contents of the second div changes.

   c. You should have code for the `onchange` event of the radio button. This code will be triggered whenever the value of the radio button changes i.e. when user selects a different device (different radio button). This code will repopulate the contents of your second div. If you're having problems populating the content dynamically, you can create a div with the right contents for each of the possible values from the first div. You set each of these div to hidden and one for the selected device will be set to visible. When user changes the value of the radio button (selects a different device), you change the value of the corresponding div from hidden to visible.

   d. Because you have a default value in the first div and the corresponding contents in the second div, the 'continue' button in the second div will always be enabled.

Comment: Hi thankyou for your replay. Ill make sure to mention all the details. When I was doing a little  research I found out that dividing the database columns into pre defined values and and the displaying it to the webapp user as option to select would also be a possible way and we can also store the inputs made by the user. Is there any possible way to do that and if so can you share any docs, sources or anything available regarding that. Thankyou, Regards.

Comment: I don't understand your comment & I don't know what it has to do with your original question. Pl